# Change primary and secondary colors in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, themes

I have a React app using Material UI. When you import a button, you can set its style using `primary={true}` or `secondary={true}`. I want to change the `primary` and `secondary` colors. I found out that I can do that this way:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: '#00bcd4',
    secondary: '#ff4081'
  }
});
```

and then here I can use it:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App/>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

But I got an error: `createMuiTheme is not a function...`

I went into the Material UI package and found out that there is no such file and when I import `createMuiTheme`, I get `undefined`. It's supposed to be imported from `material-ui/styles/theme` but it actually doesn't have this folder at all!

I was using `material-ui@0.19.4`. I updated this package to `v20` and there is still no such folder anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two diferrences with the documentation i noticed is the name of the prop for the MuiThemeProvider:

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
   <AppBar title="My AppBar" />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

And the function is not createMuiTheme but getMuiTheme:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
```

**Update:**

If you open the light theme from the package, they are not using primary or secondary, maybe you should try like that?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are using the 1.0 documentation you should use this one:
http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Comment: Why is it so darn complicated to change a color? That can be done using *one* CSS variable. Also, it's `createMuiTheme` per https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/ (not `get`).

Answer (score 67):

#### New Answer

With the latest version of Material UI, createMuiTheme is deprecated now. Hence, instead of that we should use `createTheme`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Root from './Root';

// use default theme
// const theme = createTheme();

// Or Create your Own theme:
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: '#E33E7F'
    }
  }
});
    
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Root />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
    
render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

#### Old answer

From https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Root from './Root';

// use default theme
// const theme = createMuiTheme();

// Or Create your Own theme:
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: '#E33E7F'
    }
  }
});
    
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Root />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
    
render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: With the latest version of Material UI, createMuiTheme is deprecated now. Hence, instead of that use createTheme

Answer (score 8):

You should be using [v1-beta](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) as the docs recommend. I had these issues myself and realised that I was using an outdated version of MUI.

`npm install material-ui@next`

Import:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
```

Create your theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        secondary: {
            main: '#d32f2f'
        }
      },
});
```

Apply it to your button:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <Button
     onClick={this.someMethod} 
     variant="raised"
     color="secondary" 
   </Button>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Usually if you get any `import` issues regarding MUI, then it's almost every time some version problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a custom color, put it in the `main` property of an object. MUI will use that color to calculate the dark, light and contrastText values besides the main one.

- `dark`, `light`: a darker and lighter versions of the `main` color.
- `contrastText`: the color of the text if the background color is the `main` color.

The example below:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff0000', // very red
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#00fff0', // very cyan
    },
  },
});
```

Generates the following color properties in the primary and secondary object:

```
const theme = useTheme();
const { main, dark, light, contrastText } = theme.palette.primary;
// same with secondary
// const { main, dark, light, contrastText } = theme.palette.secondary;
```

[image]

You can also use [MUI colors](https://mui.com/customization/color/#color-palette) by passing the color object directly to `primary` or `secondary` property. This time, MUI uses the property `500` (for example `amber[500]`) to calculate 3 other colors. The code below:

```
import { amber, deepPurple } from '@mui/material/colors';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: amber,
    secondary: deepPurple,
  },
});
```

Generates the following color properties in the primary and secondary object, Note that because you pass the whole color, all other shades from `50` to `A700` are also available as a small side-effect:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related Answers

- [How to add custom MUI palette colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264263/9449426)
- [Material-UI: how to access all palette shades inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67015020/9449426)

Answer (score 3):

The new API for MUI Material v5 is described in https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: red[500],
    },
  },
});

const App = () => 
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>...</ThemeProvider>;
```

Comment: ThemeProvider helped me. Thanks!