# Material-UI: how to access all palette shades inside component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

To customize my Material UI palette, I've done something like this to set up my theme:

```
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
  },
});
```

`blue` contains many shades, as shown below:

[image]

Now how do I access all the shades of `primary` palette inside of my component? Accessing all the shades of `palette.grey` is easy as shown below:

[image]

But I can't seem to access the shades of `primary` other than `main`, `dark`, `light`, and `contrastColor`, as shown below:

[image]

How do I access all the shades (e.g. `theme.palette.primary.A100`) from my component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Now how do I access all the shades of primary palette inside of my component?

I think there is a misunderstanding here. You can already access variants of the theme color (`dark`, `light`, `contrastText`), but if what you mean is all shades from the color object (`blue[100]`, `blue[200]`,...). Then no, `createTheme()` does not generate that for you automatically.

From Material-UI [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#playground):

> Only the main shades need be provided (unless you wish to further
> customize `light`, `dark` or `contrastText`), as the other colors will be
> calculated by `createTheme()`, as described in the Theme
> customization section.

When you supply only 1 color to the `main` property like below:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#607d8b"
    }
  }
});
```

Material-UI will calculate the `light`, `dark` variants of that color along with `contrastText` for the text color. You can log the `theme.palette.main` to confirm this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  console.log(theme.palette.main);
  return {};
});
```

```
{
  main: "#607d8b",
  light: "rgb(127, 151, 162)",
  dark: "rgb(67, 87, 97)",
  contrastText: "#fff",
}
```

If you however decide to pass a [color object](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#using-a-color-object):

```js
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
  },
});
```

Then Material-UI will find the main shade of that object. Default is [`blue[500]`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1b718c1110f6392fdc1f4bd6be36f719dd3168a2/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L162-L164), and calculate the `dark`, `light` and `contrastText` based on the `main` color as normal. The end result will look like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  console.log(theme.palette.main);
  return {};
});
```

```
{
  50: "#eceff1",
  100: "#cfd8dc",
  200: "#b0bec5",
  300: "#90a4ae",
  400: "#78909c",
  500: "#607d8b", // createPalette() uses this color as main
  600: "#546e7a",
  700: "#455a64",
  800: "#37474f",
  900: "#263238",
  A100: "#cfd8dc",
  A200: "#b0bec5",
  A400: "#78909c",
  A700: "#455a64",
  main: "#607d8b", // added from createPalette()
  light: "#90a4ae", // added from createPalette()
  dark: "#455a64", // added from createPalette()
  contrastText: "#fff", // added from createPalette()
}
```

### Typescript Usage

As [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20995) issue points out, if you are using Typescript, you may realize that it does not give you the shades information in the theme `PaletteColor`.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  const shade = theme.palette.main[500]; // shade is any instead of string
  return {};
});
```

The solution as the maintainer suggested is to use *module augmentation* to extend the `PaletteColor` definition:

```js
import { ColorPartial } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  interface PaletteColor extends ColorPartial {}
}
```

If you are using [this](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1) linter rule suggestion to avoid importing private modules (anything deeper than 2 level imports). You can create `ColorPartial` yourself easily like this:

```js
import { Color } from "@material-ui/core";

type ColorPartial = Partial<Color>;

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette" {
  interface PaletteColor extends ColorPartial {}
}
```

Now typescript is aware of all possible shades in your `PaletteColor`:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  const shade = theme.palette.main[500]; // shade is string
  return {};
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67013112/material-ui-how-to-access-all-palette-shades-inside-component]

Comment: Very nice, works really well! It turns out that it was TypeScript that was throwing me off. I can only get this to work if I add `//@ts-ignore` on top of `theme.palette.primary[500]`, otherwise I get this error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '500' can't be used to index type 'PaletteColor'.  TS7053`. Your codesandbox doesn't seem to have that problem. How did you get TypeScript to allow the `500` indexer on `PaletteColor`?

Comment: Here's my sandbox. I can get it to work, but the code editor shows type errors. In VS Code, it won't even run unless I add `//@ts-ignore`. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-access-all-palette-shades-inside-components-gimgx?file=/src/demo.tsx

Comment: @JohnnyOshika I just copied the tsconfig in my working sandbox to yours and it still throws error. Not sure why mine works because it's [not supposed to](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20995#issuecomment-626904458). One solution is to use module augmentation to extend `PaletteColor`. See [this](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors) example. Hit me up if you need an example of `PaletteColor` extention.

Comment: @NearHuscari I tried module augmentation. While it works with custom palette names (e.g. `primaryShades` is what I'm using), it doesn't when I want to augment a standard name like `primary` as `Color`, as it's already defined as `PaletteColor`. The error I get is this: `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'primary' must be of type 'PaletteColor', but here has type 'Color'.ts(2717)`

Comment: My working solution is this custom palette that I create (`primaryShades`), which works well enough. It would be nice to use the default `primary`, however.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika You don't really need `primaryShades`. I made a typescript example for you.

Comment: @NearHuscari Well that's awesome! I'll delete my answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Material UI color systems docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/), it automatically calculates several values, such as `dark`, `light`, `main`. However, for more variant, it says using [color objects](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#default-values) such as `@material-ui/core/colors/blue`. it is maybe the `blue` you used in your first example code.

Color objects have a structure like below. [github link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/colors/blue.js)

```js
const blue = {
  50: '#e3f2fd',
  100: '#bbdefb',
  200: '#90caf9',
  300: '#64b5f6',
  400: '#42a5f5',
  500: '#2196f3',
  600: '#1e88e5',
  700: '#1976d2',
  800: '#1565c0',
  900: '#0d47a1',
  A100: '#82b1ff',
  A200: '#448aff',
  A400: '#2979ff',
  A700: '#2962ff',
};

export default blue;
```

So if you want to use more variants for colors that are not served as [color object](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#2014-material-design-color-palettes), you should make color variance youreserlf.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access those different shades of blue in my React components? The theme gets injected to `makeStyles` but I can't seem to access the shades of primary color there. Are you suggesting I hard code those values in a global `blue` module and import that module? That would be bypassing the Material UI theme.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should make a function like `createPalette` or override this. [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/661e595db02628a247bb8e529fb98aa92c0bb3b2/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js)