# Material-UI styled component rendered in indigo when no such color defined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to build a NextJS app with Material-UI drawing inspiration from a boilerplate I found at https://github.com/phuongnq/nextjs-material-design-boilerplate.

My implementation can be reviewed at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web.

The boilerplate in question defines a default theme color palette as **lightBlue** for primary and **green** for secondary. However, it doesn't define anything explicitly for the button text color. By default, all button text should be **white**, but when rendered, this code shows a **lightBlue** button with **black** text. My question is, why is it changing the default text color for buttons and where in the code can I set it to **white**?

Also, when I disable the palette definitions section in `lib/getPageContext.js`:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        // primary: {
        //     light: lightBlue[300],
        //     main: lightBlue[500],
        //     dark: lightBlue[700],
        // },
        // secondary: {
        //     light: pink[300],
        //     main: pink[500],
        //     dark: pink[700],
        // },
    },
});
```

I get the primary button in **indigo** instead of the expected default of **lightBlue**. I tried looking through the entire codebase but couldn't spot this definition anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text color is controlled by the `contrastText` color in the theme. When it isn't explicitly specified, Material-UI has an algorithm for deciding whether to use black or white as the text color for a given background color.

You can find a syntax example in my answer here: [Text color not working in Material-UI Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876245/text-color-not-working-in-material-ui-theme/53889500#53889500)

You can find documentation about it here: https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#palette

As far as your second question, the code controlling the colors of the [default theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) can be found here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L81